# Startup error Uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder

Tags: 16.04, startup

Does any one know how to fix this error? I have a Dell note and it is the second time this error shows up.

```
[   1.761113]   [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reportintel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting   [i915]  *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced. 
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. 

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. 
     (i.e., without -a or options) 
Fsck exited with status code 4 
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck 

BusyBox vc. 22.1   (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built -in commands.
```

`(Initramfs) help ((i wrote ))`

```
Built-in commands:
-------------------------------
. : [alias break cd chdir command continue echo eval exec exit export false getopts hash help history let local printf pwd read readonly return set shift test times trap true type ulimit umask unalias unset wait  [  [[ acpid ash awk basename blockdev cat chmod chroot chvt clear cmp cp cut deallocvt devmem df dnsdomainname du dumpkmap echo egrep env expr false fbset fdflush fgrep find fstrim grep gunzip gzip hostname hwclock ifconfing ip kill ln loadfront loadkmap ls lzop lzopcat mkdir mkfifo mknod mkswap mktemp modinfo more mount mv openvt pidof printf ps pwd readlink reset rm rmdir sed seq setkeycodes sh sleep sort stat static-sh stty switch-root sync tail tee test touch tr true tty umount uname uniq unlzop wc wget which yes zcat
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to run a manual fsck (file system check). Something in your file system isn't right.

1. boot the computer
2. choose Advanced Options from the GRUB boot menu
3. choose recovery mode
4. choose root access
5. enter your password
6. type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
7. run #6 more than once if there are errors
8. type `reboot`

If the corrupted system won't even let you do that, then:

1. boot the Ubuntu Live DVD in "Try Ubuntu" mode
2. open terminal from the Unity dash
3. in terminal, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
4. run #3 more than once if there are errors

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  But it didn't work.  When I choose the recovery mode, the same screen appears with the built-in commands.     :(    Any recomendation?  Best regards!

Comment: Then you'll have to boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and run fsck from there. Open a terminal, and type "sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1". If it shows errors, run it more than once. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema hello, i have the same Problem, and i did what you said using live CD, i even created a forcefsck file in `/` still Boot in emergency mode , i'm on ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: @AbelTom please start a new question and I'll try and help you. Please include any error messages that you're receiving during boot, or during fsck.

Comment: @heynnema Done! http://askubuntu.com/questions/887557/ubuntu-16-10-booting-in-emergency-mode-after-upgrade-from-16-04